# Updating only one DLL file force the whole application to be updated

Tags: c#, winforms, dll

I have developed a C# Winforms application. That application is made by the EXE file and several class libraries DLL files.

It is supposed that if I modified only one DLL file, I could update, in production computer, only that DLL and the whole application should be working as always, with the new features added in the modified DLL. That is not working.

When I add features to one DLL, I need to copy the whole application files, the EXE together with all of the DLL's.

When I modify certain DLL, I modify the Assembly Version of the modified DLL and also of the EXE file. I think that is my mistake.

When I modify one DLL, how can I made the whole application to continue working by just copying the modified DLL to production computer?

Thanks
Jaime

Comment: So if it doesn't matter then don't change it.  If somebody else changed it and it *might* work anyway then you use bindingRedirect in the app.config file.  If it turned out that it actually mattered then you'll get the phone call, nothing you can do about that but pick up the phone and make it your problem.

Comment: Read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions - You can deploy the new dll with newe version number. Then update the appconfig to redirect the old version to new version.

Comment: @HansPassant I forgot to mention that the DLL's are loaded dynamically. They are not bound at compile time. The EXE file loads the files dynamically. Think about 2 DLL's, A and B. Both DLL's are referencing a DLL called Common.dll. That DLL is also being referenced in the EXE file. Now, if I change B dll and I change EXE assembly version number, and copy both to production computer, when trying to execute the program, A dll is not loaded because of Common.dll incompatibility. By the way, I need to change revision number after a bug fix. Is there a good practice for this?